# How to set 'Team name' while publishing pact contracts to pactflow?

Tags: pact

We recently started using pactflow tool for contract testing. In pactflow we can create different teams. But while publishing pacts to pactflow how to set the 'team name' or use team uuid ? we are using pact CLI to publish pacts.

we are using the below pact CLI cmd to publish pacts. There is no supported arguments for 'publish' command to set team-uuid. We use --team-uuid when using 'create-webhook' command, looking for something similar for 'publish' command

```
docker run --rm -v ${PWD}:${PWD}
pactfoundation/pact-cli publish ${{ pact_folder_path }}
--consumer-app-version ${{ git_commit_version }}
--tag ${{ git_branch }}
--broker-base-url ${{ pact_broker_url }}
--broker-token ${{ pact_broker_token }}
```

Comment: Why did you mark down the answer?

Answer (score -1):

The application to team association is done through the [team](https://docs.pactflow.io/docs/user-interface/settings/teams) UI.

You can associate applications (pacticipants) and users to a team. Any contract publications will use this association.

We currently don't have a specific CLI command to add the team to the publish, and the default behaviour is to assign to the "default" team.